# Connecting Veency on Iphone from another network

Tags: ip, port, nat, portforwarding

I installed **Veency Server** on my old Iphone 3GS. I can connect to it from my other devices in local network, using its *192.168.2.xxx* adress, but i cant connect from another network. I know that my router uses **NAT** so i tried port forwarding for ports **5500**,**5900** and **5800**, then i tried to forward all ports in range **0:7000** but none of them seemed to work. What can i do ?

Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be too complicated.

Set a DHCP reservation in your router for the device.
Forward the VNC port (Usually 5900) to the IP you set.
If you don't have a static external IP, get something like No-IP or DynDNS so you can have an unchanging URL to connect to.
That's about it, it's no different than making any other service external.

You should know that this will not be secure, and very easy for a man in the middle attack to happen.